# How do I change to ksh?

Tags: command-line, ksh

I need to learn some ksh details, but i don't want to change from bash to ksh permanently.

What should i do?

Is it possible to change shell only for a specific console session?

Answer (score 6):

If you don't already have ksh installed, enter `sudo apt-get install ksh` in the terminal.
After installation you can enter a ksh session by entering `ksh` in the terminal. When you are finished with ksh just type `exit`.

Answer (score 0):

After installing `ksh`, you can also use the command `exec ksh` to replace your existing shell.  Then, when you exit `ksh` that console is closed.

Not as important now, but used to be terribly important when we had 150 users all sharing the same limited machine.

`exec ksh` at the end of your `.bashrc` should do it -- but then it would affect every every interactive shell.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt-get install ksh` then start ksh simply by typing `ksh` in a terminal window. `Exit` when you are done to return to your default shell.